# PHP MySQL UPDATE Failure Change INT Value from 0 to 1 with PHP Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to create a small script that will basically replace the value of an already existing mysql table array. The table has the row "claimed" which has a default value of 0, and is an enum of "0", "1" (can switch to a INT or Text if that helps but hasn't helped when I tried).

The idea is that my game server will call to the database and if the value is either a 0 or a 1, a different action is performed. Someone please help!

I cannot get the Claimed Row Value to update from 0 to 1 with my script that my game servers calls to read a single line of text for its value.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['username'])){
    if(!empty($_GET['username'])){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_GET['username']));
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM donations WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1") or die("MYSQL");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($count == 1){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $claimed = $row["claimed"];
                $amount = $row["amount"];
                $package = $row["package"];

                if($claimed == 0){
                    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE claimed SET claimed='1' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
                    if($sql){
                        die($package);
                    }else{
                        die("MYSQL");
                    }
                }else{die("CLAIMED");}

            }
        }else{die("EMPTY");}

    }else{die("EMPTY");}
}

?>
```

Comment: You have to different tables "donations" for select and "claimed" for an update. Is it the way you wanted to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE claimed SET claimed='1' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

Change to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE donations SET claimed='1' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

**Syntax for update:**

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value where ...
```

And Stop using mysql_* as it is deprecated use mysqli_ or pdo